# How to inherit one abbrev table in another abbrev table?

Tags: org-mode, latex, abbrev

I've defined a lot of abbrevs in `latex-mode-abbrev-table` and I'd like to use all the contents in `latex-mode-abbrev-table` and `org-mode-abbrev-table` when in `org-mode`.

A possible "solution" would be to write all the abbrevs in `global-abbrev-table` but I'd like to keep the global table clean.

So how can I use the *merged* version(LaTeX + Org) of abbrev table in `org-mode`?

Comment: that's a good idea! I don't think abbrevs support any kind of inheritance to link one table to another. You could just copy all your latex abbrevs into your org-mode abbrev table, but that would mean you have to maintain the two tables in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the
[`:parents` property](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Abbrev-Table-Properties.html#Abbrev-Table-Properties) to
hold a list of tables from which to inherit abbrevs.

In your case, you can do:

```el
(abbrev-table-put org-mode-abbrev-table
                  :parents (list latex-mode-abbrev-table))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the original answer is working for you, but the difficulty I had with it was that abbrevs added in the two modes were added to separate tables. This meant that if I added new autocorrects in `org-mode`, they would not be available in `latex-mode`.  I'm not sure if this is what you want, but I did a two-way merge by setting the `local-abbrev-table` in a hook that I configure when I load the `abbrev-mode` package. For your case this would be something like:

```
(use-package abbrev-mode
  :init
  (setq-default abbrev-mode t)
  ;; a hook function that sets the abbrev-table to org-mode-abbrev-table
  ;; whenever the major mode is a text mode
  (defun mwp-set-text-mode-abbrev-table ()
    (if (derived-mode-p 'org-mode)
        (setq local-abbrev-table latex-mode-abbrev-table)))
  :commands abbrev-mode
  :hook
  (abbrev-mode . mwp-set-text-mode-abbrev-table)
```

See also my similar question here: [use a single abbrev-table for multiple modes?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45462/use-a-single-abbrev-table-for-multiple-modes/45476#45476)